# Unable to Register Managed Account

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server, records-management, managed-account

When I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923%28v=office.15%29 ,section *Create an isolated app domain on your development computer* step 5, I should create a new managerAccount. But i get this massage every time when I try to create a new account:[image]

I run it in this: **Administrator: SharePoint 2013 management shell**

My domain name for SharePoint is sp.com and when the create window appear I have entered this:

Account name: SP\spManager

Password: Ecutbildning01

(It's a local server for school, not on the internet)

My ultimate goal is to be able to use apps on SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
 $cred = Get-Credential -credential SP\spManager
 New-SPManagedAccount -credential $cred
```

or

```
  $user = "SP\spManager"
  $pWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String "Ecutbildning01" –AsPlainText -Force
  $cred = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $user, $pWord
  New-SPManagedAccount -credential $cred
```

Comment: Thanks, you seems to know the answers to my questions. If it's okej could I e-mail you other questions that might come up?

Comment: Haha, I am wicked at Googling. But keep asking your questions here, that way they will draw attention from all great community members :)